# SQL Server: Function is returning single char in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Here is function (splitting string and returning int values)

```
USE [SANNET]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata int 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(CAST(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)AS  int))
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
GO
```

Everything is ok when using this way

```
select * from fnSplitString('65,1,2,27,28,33,34',',')
/**
Returning
splitdata
-----------
65
1
2
27
28
33
34

(7 row(s) affected)


*/
```

But when i use in stored procedure is returning a single char (not even a row)

```
-- Procedure which calling the function


CREATE /*ALTER*/ PROCEDURE [dbo].[CallerProcedure] 
    @values varchar
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select * from fnSplitString(@values,',');

END
GO
```

Usage

```
DECLARE @result int

EXEC    @result = [dbo].[CallerProcedure]
        @values = '65,1,2,27,28,33,34'

SELECT @result

GO
/*
Returns
splitdata
-----------
6


-----------
0
```

(1 row(s) affected)

*/

As you see even value "64" is not returned. Just returnet 6.

Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Start using `OUTPUT` variables, if you want to return values form a stored procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not defined a length for your VARCHAR input variable @values, so it is defaulting to `VARCHAR(1)`:

```
CREATE /*ALTER*/ PROCEDURE [dbo].[CallerProcedure] 
    @values varchar
```

So although you think you are passing `'65,1,2,27,28,33,34'`, this is truncated to just `'6'`

Changing the declaration of @Values to `VARCHAR(MAX)` will solve your problem.

```
CREATE /*ALTER*/ PROCEDURE [dbo].[CallerProcedure] 
    @values VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select * from fnSplitString(@values,',');

END
GO
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a68c4/2)**

You should **ALWAYS** define a length when converting to, or declaring a VARCHAR. For further reading:

**[Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)**

Answer (score 1):

Modify your procedure as follows. First insert results into a variable table and than return it. Also don't forget to set size for `VARCHAR` fields.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CallerProcedure] @values VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE
        (
            value VARCHAR(20)
        )

        INSERT INTO @MyTable
        SELECT *
            FROM fnSplitString(@values, ',');

        SELECT *
        FROM @MyTable
    END
GO
```